# Assigning categories to a text cell using approximate or partial keyword matching

Tags: excel, vlookup

I would like to be able to to bulk assign specific categories in column B to the text cells located in column A, based on the words found in the cells. I can do this using a VLookup, however it only works for EXACT match terms specified in the Vlookup category values table.

[image: Vlookup categories]

*link anchor text categories are used for this example

Is there a standard formula which i can use to label categories based on APPROXIMATE or PARTIAL phrase matches and not just EXACT. Obviously anchor text usage is very diverse and would be impossible to label with EXACT.

So in theory, the cell in column A would be given a category even it only included part of the word.

The formula I am using at the moment is:

=VLOOKUP("*"&A4&"*",C:D,2,FALSE)

And it manages to work with one APPROXIMATE match only.

I am a bit of a novice in Excel, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to match multiple patterns I would go with regular expressions in such case [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)